# Trying to customize devise views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So, basically I have 2 users in my app, they are Company and Establishment.

The problem is that I want to customize the edit view for each one of them, but **edit_company_registration** and **edit_establishment_registration** are rendering **views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb** instead of **views/company/registrations/edit.html.erb** and **views/establishment/registrations/edit.html.erb** respectively, so I can't customize each one of them separately, and in addition to that problem whenever I try to edit a record (Company or Establishment) I get this error.

[image]

I don't know why is this happening (and I obviously fill all the fields), I don't know if this is part of the effect of the above (the fact that links to **edit_company_registration** and **edit_establishment_registration** are rendering **views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**).

Telling a little what I did, I used this command:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

To have the views of devise in **app/views/company** and **app/views/admin** like this:

[image]

But as I said, if I try to go to **edit_establishment_registration** or **edit_company_registration** it will render **devise/registrations#edit** instead of **establishment/registrations/edit.html.erb** and **company/registrations/edit.html.erb**respectively, how can I fix this (or these) problem?, I need help please.

If you are little confused, this is what I want to do:

1. Be able to customize each edit view separately, for this I guess I have to somehow make it render **views/establishment/registrations/edit.html.erb** from **edit_establishment_registration** (same case for company).
2. Fix the problem that tells me that the password can't be blank (Maybe it's a side effect of the fact that both **edit_company_registration** and **edit_establishment_registration** are rendering **views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**, I don't know).

Greetings.

Comment: We'll need more information. Please include your routes.rb file (relevant to the changes you've made to support your requirements). Also include a sample of the form data as per server logs whenever you submit the form with the current password filled in. Your controller changes will also be helpful.

Comment: maybe `permitted_params` is the issue for respective controller!

Comment: There are a bunch of issues - I could write an answer but it won't be conclusive. Would you like me to do that for you?